# Summing all rows above the current row based on the values

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and Stackoverflow so please forgive me if the question I ask has been answered in a previous thread.

I am working with a Python data frame similar to the one below. I wish to have a "Build up Balance" for each client which is the sum of the balances up to that particular row. So for example cell D6 in the attached image is the sum of the balances for John for all his account appearing between row 2 and row 6. Thanks in advance. Keep it simple.

[image]

Comment: "Keep it simple"...? Of all the nerve... this isn't a sweatshop to order code as you please. You'd better show us what you've done, and links to pictures don't fly - try actually pasting your data in text form. Show a little effort when writing a question, thanks.

Comment: I am very new to python hence the request to keep it simple. Now, I didn't know how else to paste the data but ideally the data is as in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple? Where do you want to begin?
If you are as new to python as you say, use pandas for working with data frames.
Then the following will sum a column you want and assign it to a variable

```
sum_column = df['column_name'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks J.k for the response. Assume the build-up balances in the image was not there, how would I go about coming up with it?